# SQLPlus stopped working

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

Windows 7 64-bit. 
OracleXE installed since February.
Oracle instantclient 11.2 installed as well, so I have both c:\oracle\ and c:\oraclexe.

I use SQLPlus every day. 
It's location is C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\sqlplus.exe

I have not changed my environment variables during this 6 month period.

Yet, suddenly, SQLPlus stopped working. Permanently. Even after reboots:

```
Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

Now there are *TONS AND TONS* of pages of people discussing this exact problem.  Every single solution involves setting ORACLE_HOME.  None of these fix my problems. In fact, ORACLE_HOME was not an environment variable at any point between February and today!

These pages are all repeats of each other, and I've satisfied every solution condition on every one of those pages to no avail. And they are almost wholly about people who *JUST* installed Oracle.

But what about me?  My install was perfect for 6 months, and just rotted away one day without me changing anything.

1) I've done the set ORACLE_HOME=c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\ to no avail. I've also taken about 10 shots in the dark with setting it to different levels in that path (like c:\oraclexe), but everything I've read suggestions it should point to the server folder.

2) I know it's not a path problem because I have no problem running SQLPlus. The error is generated by SQLPlus.

3) I've tried set LANG=us {even though I didn't need this at any point in the past}

4) I've even tried set NLS_LANG=American_America.we8iso8859p15 to no avail.

5) Yes, sp1us.msb is indeed at: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\sqlplus\mesg\sp1us.msb

6) I've even used Sysinternals Procmon to see where SQLPlus.exe is looking. It's a lot of output to wade through and I'm not too familiar with the tool, but it seems to indicate that SQLPlus is looking for the file... Right where it is! So why can't it find it?

7) I don't think it's file permissions. Ran fine for 6 months. I've ensured that I own the files via takeown and icalcs -- but only after the problems started.

8) It's not antivirus.

Twice I've mucked around and managed to get it run correctly, and both times it only ran once and stopped working correctly. So I could never verify a step that consistently got it to work. It makes no sense to me that it would run once, but not twice - It's almost as if SQLPlus itself is changing the environment to prevent SQLPlus from working.

Comment: File permission problem maybe? Or your anti-virus blocking access to the file? Or the file is corrupted?

Comment: 1) Not a permission problem; I actually use icalcs and takeown to ensure I own all files.

2) Not anti-virus: Suspending anti-virus has same results.

3) How would I be able to find out if it is corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!

I was setting an environment varaible SQLPLUS in my own script. 
I was using it for non-Oracle-specific purposes.

I guess I collided with a variable they wanted to use.

Strangely, I've been using this script (a sqlplus.bat that forks to different sqlplus behavior) for 2 years, and my choice in temporary environment variable only presented a problem this week.

Very odd!

Comment: Setlocal/endlocal is your friend.